# Noun for "Clueless"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example:

> After an hour of research and **[cluelessness]**, I finally got it to work.

I need a word to replace that word, since apparently it isn't a real word.

Comment: ***Cluelessness***  - 
Total stupidity or ignorance : cluelessness in that department - http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cluelessness

Comment: Hmm.... But chrome says it's a typo... Sorry, should've looked further

Comment: Chrome isn't the definer of language. Not yet at least.

Comment: Bewilderment, mystification, perplexity, ...

Comment: ‘Alicia Silverstone’?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cluelessness is a perfectly acceptable word. It's in my Chamber's dictionary anyway.

But you could say "head-scratching" or "groping in the dark" or "trial and error" or "frustration" or "perplexity"...

My favorite is:

> After an hour of research and head-scratching, I finally got it to work.

Comment: I'm really not trying to be snarky or sarcastic but while "groping the dark" gave me a really great image that made me laugh, I do believe it's usually "groping *in* the dark."